# Is there a DTD or Schema file for jsp tag files?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am writing some JSP 2.x tag files. I have searched for a few hours now, but I was not able to find doctype/schema definitions/dtds for jsp based tag files.

Does anybody knows if there are dtd/schema files to ease the pain of writing those tag files?
It's pretty painful to not have auto completion and so on in eclipse. I have to check in the few tutorials I have found when writing tags.

To clarify:
I am not talking about java based tags, nor the taglib tld files. I am talking about tag files that consist of jsp code, usually with the ending .tag or tagx and they are located in META-INF/tags or WEB-INF/tags.

Hints are highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.
[Look here](https://svn.codehaus.org/jetty/servlet-api/branches/servlet-2.5/src/main/resources/javax/servlet/jsp/resources/jspxml.dtd)

The syntax reference with links to the dtd is [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref20.html).

Comment: This seems to be "just" the jsp dtd and doesn't contain the pure "tag" related elements like "tag" and "attribute" that are located at the beginning of the tag file.

Comment: check the second link I#ve edited. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the second link that is a great resource!

Comment: Both links are dead (Thanks for nothing, Oracle!). The [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090228064218/http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref20.html) doesn't contain links to a DTD.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't choose jsp as layout technology anymore. Thymeleaf for example is IMHO far superior. But some projects are stuck on JSP for the time being, and I am sad for you ;-)

Comment: Agree with Patrick. I would go for AngularJS JSP is deprecated

Comment: We're using a framework which comes with a JSP frontend. Rewriting it is out of question.